# Issue in Asterisk Performance

Tags: centos, asterisk

I am running FreePBX on DigitalOcean VM. I am facing some call dropping issue in Asterisk. When looking at "htop", "top" and FreePBX GUI, I see different results of CPU utilization and can't understand if my VM is OK or needs attention w.r.t CPU. Load average shows nearly idle system while CPU utilization of Asterisk process is pretty high.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Could someone please advise me on this? 74% CPU on a process yet idle system on load average. Can this be an issue causing call dropping on Asterisk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using sar (http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/03/sar-examples/) to track cpu usage, and also the Asterisk CDR to track call records. If you find a correlation between high CPU usage and dropped calls, then yes you are likely right.

I suppose it is possible that the load average feature isn't working right, virtual servers can be a bit funky that way in regards to inaccurate hardware reporting, though this particular feature has always worked for me.

Comment: I rebuilt machine on a new VPS (again on Digital Ocean) and things are working perfect now. Seems like it was a glitch in Asterisk itself. I didn't know about "sar" but experienced it just now and I found it to be a really helpful Admin tool to diagnose problems with the system. I also agree that load average wasn't reporting correct stats.

Answer (score 1):

Digital Ocean in virtualized platform

On virtualized platform both load average and cpu mean nothing in term of voice quality.

You will experience call drops when host server will not give you enought fast cpu slices. That can happens on 0% or at 70%, nobody can say that except host's admins. There are no any data about that for Digital Ocean.

Try change vps to more powerfull one or  change vps provider.